# Sonarqube can't connect to postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, sonarqube

I'm using docker compose to deploy sonarqube.

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: mc1arke/sonarqube-with-community-branch-plugin:lts
    depends_on:
      - sonar_db
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://sonar_db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqubelts/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqubelts/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqubeltsx/logs
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
  sonar_db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
      POSTGRES_DB: sonar        
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql13
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql13/data

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

Postgres instance starts fine, but sonarqube doesn't. The log is:

```
024.02.19 20:40:22 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting Web Server
2024.02.19 20:40:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 9.9.3.79811 / 4fefd8061afc12c43078b4cee31db2e4618b4fd6
2024.02.19 20:40:23 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://sonar_db:5432/sonar
2024.02.19 20:40:23 INFO  web[][c.z.h.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024.02.19 20:40:34 ERROR web[][c.z.h.p.HikariPool] HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.createHikariDataSource(DefaultDatabase.java:159)
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.initDataSource(DefaultDatabase.java:148)
    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:126)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(StartableBeanPostProcessor.java:33)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:80)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel1.start(PlatformLevel1.java:164)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.start(PlatformImpl.java:196)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.startLevel1Container(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.init(PlatformImpl.java:76)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:55)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:104)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
2024.02.19 20:40:34 WARN  web[][o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1021f6c9-org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1021f6c9-org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
```

Docker network is the same for both components.
If I login in the postgres container, I can use the database. Also on that container I can't do "sudo apt-get update", it returns a DNS error. So I'm guessing that it could be a network problem but I'm not sure where to start.

What could be the error?